# Getting controller name and action name from url

Tags: url, cakephp, controller, action

I'm searching for an easy way to "translate" url strings into arrays of controller/action name pairs.

example1:

```
/users/
```

should return

```
array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'index')
```

example2:

```
/admin/users/view/23
```

should return

```
array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'admin_view')
```

example3:

```
/
```

should return

```
array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'home')
```

Comment: What's wrong with `$this->params` in the controller or in which other situation do you want to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Router::parse`](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/router#method-Routerparse) could do it.

E.g.:

```
 <?php debug(Router::parse('/admin/users/index')) ?>
```

It is not exactly what you described, but chances are that this format is even better for further use, if you "stay" in cake.